# Enabling the dock icon on Mac with WxPython

Tags: python, macos, window, wxpython, hide

I'm trying to get my empty frame so that when I click the X it just hides the window, and then if I hit the dock icon it'll reveal the window. It's turning out to be more of a challenge than I expected.. I used http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/ but I can't make ends of it.

Here's my code:

```
import wx

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, "title",style=wx.SYSTEM_MENU | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION, size=(300,300))
    panel = wx.Panel(self)


    def MacReopenApp(self, event):
         print "Attempting to reveal the window."

    def MacHideApp(self, event):
        print "Attempting to hide the window."


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Frame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

The document you link to states that you need to add those event handlers on the App. You have currently defined them on a frame. So you need to extend `wx.App` and define those event handlers, and instantiate your own `App` instead of `wx.App`.

So (shortened example copied from [your link](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X/)):

```
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.App.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        # This catches events when the app is asked to activate by some other
        # process
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_ACTIVATE_APP, self.OnActivate)

    #.....

    def MacReopenApp(self):
        """Called when the doc icon is clicked, and ???"""
        self.BringWindowToFront()

app = MyApp(False)
app.MainLoop()
```